# How to get all the entity details which are using specific media?

Tags: 8, entities, media

I have a image "sample.jpg" (In media library) and I used this image in multiple custom blocks of different block types.

Now I need an information of all the custom blocks which are using "sample.jpg" image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Jdrupal, with reference to your answer I have updated 'block' to 'block_content' and it is working fine.

```
        $blocks = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('block_content')
      ->loadByProperties(['logo1' => $media_id_1, 'logo2' => $media_id_2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `entityTypeManager`, like this:

```
$blocks = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('block')->loadByProperties(['field_media_1' => $media_id, 'field_media_2' => $media_id]);
```

Where $media_id the the is of your media entity.

That will give you all the blocks that references that media entity.

Comment: Sorry it is not working, I am getting NULL

Comment: You have to replace field_media with the field name if the media field, it has to be the same everywhere for it to work

Comment: Oh Okay, Thank you. But I have different field names, Is there any solution for that case ?

Comment: Look at updated answer